# Could not load type when changing the interface

Tags: c#, sdk, backwards-compatibility

I'm developing SDK that has abstract class Example.
In the new SDK version I Split the abstract class so part of the parameters will be on Example_BaseClass. so "Example" inherits from "Example_BaseClass".
Programmers who used the Example class not supposed to be effected of this change.

The problem that if I compile my code (kind of plugin on my system) with the new SDK and put it on old software version (with old SDK) it throws exception:
'Could not load type 'Example_BaseClass' from assembly'

It like it search for the new class although it supposed to be transparent.
Is it even possible to keep this kind of backward compatibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your new SDK, `Example` class *depends* on `Example_BaseClass`. So when you compiled your plugin with new SDK, the compiled code looks like this:

- Main code depends on `Example` (accesses some methods or is inherited from it)
- `Example` depends on `Example_BaseClass`. It tries to find it and fails with runtime exception.

As for how to maintain backward-compatibility. C# compiles to Intermediate Layer rather than binary code (assembly). This lets C# have certain benefits, like reflection. But it comes at cost (like you see). Unless guys at [CoreRT repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) give us a way to compile code natively into binaries, the only way I see is publishing you SDK as nuget package, update it frequently, and let people `dotnet restore` it often.